# how to implment click-once submit button in asp.net mvc 2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, submit

I need to implement a click-once button for my asp.net mvc 2 application. I have just a very simple submit form, and when the user clicks on the submit button, I need to change its image to a "please wait..." type of graphics and disables the click event for further submits until the server comes back.

Is there an example or code snippet for this? I used to be able to do it in the asp.net webforms, but that technique does not apply here.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable the submit button when you submit the form you can use the onSubmit function for the form and call a javascript function that will disable the button.

For example:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Organisation", FormMethod.Post, new { autocomplete = "off", onsubmit = "disableSubmitButton()" }))
   { %>
       //Your code

      <input id="buttonName" type="submit" value="Create"/>
  <% } %>
```

and then in your javascript section:

```
function disableSubmitButton() {

    document.getElementById("buttonName").disabled = true;

};
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: and using jQuery you can extend this to disable multiple buttons (e.g. 'OK', 'Cancel', etc.) with something like $(':input').attr('disabled', true)

Comment: so i found 1 problem with this approach is that if the client or server validation fails, the submit button will stay as disabled. is there a way to catch that failed event and re-enable the submit button if validation fails? thanks again.

Comment: You could add some logic to the view that would check if ViewData.ModelState.IsValid is false and if so then run some javascript to enable the button? It could be disputed that you should not have any logic in your views though - but I can't think of another solution.

Comment: I found that this didn't send the value of the button back to the controller if you were using that to work out which button had been clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example of how create ajax login using asp.net mvc and jQuery:
[How to implement a Client-side Ajax Login on Asp.Net MVC (A link to the solution for Asp.Net Webforms is in here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210483/how-to-implement-a-client-side-ajax-login-on-asp-net-mvc-a-link-to-the-solution)

Comment: that solution seems too complicated for me. i don't want to deal with ajax as my form is a very simple submit form. all i want is to disable the submit button.