# ASP.NET MVC 3.0 - User Hammering Submit Button

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Even using the Post/Redirect/Get method, and including javascript to disable a button after it has been clicked, I am having a problem with users being able to just rapidly hammer a submit button and get multiple form posts in before server side validation can stop it.

Is there any way to stop this? I've even tried this method : [how to implment click-once submit button in asp.net mvc 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764059/how-to-implment-click-once-submit-button-in-asp-net-mvc-2)

And I've tried outright blocking the UI with jquery blockUI. I have BOTH client side **and** server side validation in place, and they work perfectly - but a user smashing the submit button twenty times in under a second just seems to keep breaking it.

Comment: Blocking the UI with javascript is the most sure way to handle this. It seems to me you have done everything you can. Is this a real user or a tester hitting the submit button?

Comment: Is your post method idempotent?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. My post method is different from my initial view method, yes. I have a `Create` and then an `[HttpPost]Create` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use javascript to wire the `onclick` event to disable the button.

If you are already doing that and you can still get multiple form posts, then the problem is a delay between the clicking of the button and the button being disabled, and you must be submitting the form multiple times during this delay.

To fix this, make the `onclick` event first make a call to `stopPropagation()` to stop the submit event.  Then validate that the form is not in submission-blocked state.  You can do this by creating a page-scoped javascript variable with a boolean value like `can_submit`.  Test for can_submit being true before submitting the form.  Set the `can_submit = false` when the button is disabled, so even if the button is not disabled fast enough, the form will not submit if the value has already been set to false.

Comment: This only works if the user has javascript enabled, though. I implemented it and quickly my tester was able to bypass it by going through their phone browser.

Comment: You can create an HttpContext input queue on your HttpApplication and test for duplicate consecutive post requests.  Cancel the ones that shouldn't go through.

Comment: This sounds like an intelligent approach, any idea where I would start for something like that? I've never heard of doing such a thing.

Comment: Yes.  There's a variety of ways you can do this.  Since you're using MVC, I think the easiest would be to implement a custom IRouteHandler.  You can subclass MvcRouteHandler.  You can put your logic in an override of the GetHttpHandler method.  If it's a duplicate request then just return an HttpHandler that doesn't do anything, otherwise defer the call to base.GetHttpHandler

Comment: How would I be able to tell if it was a duplicate request? I've never dealt with the RouteHandler class before.

Comment: It gives your a RequestContext, which encapsulates the RouteData and the HttpContext.  Between RouteData and HttpContext.Request, you should have everything you need.  (Same URL, both Post requests, same form collection in Request.Form)...

Comment: I'm still not entirely sure how to do this, but I'll give it a try. So I basically want to make a RouteHandler, and store when the user submits the page based on their identity, and then prevent it from being executed again?

Comment: Yep, I would do something like have a Dictionary<string,List<RequestSummary>> where the key is the session id and the RequestSummary is a simple object that contains all the values needed to determine equality of the http request content and a datetime.  So, if the datetime is less than a second before the last submission from the session with the specified session id, then you will compare the incoming request to the last RequestSummary, then if it's the same submission, you can return the HttpHandler that doesn't do anything, otherwise use base.GetHttpHandler.

Comment: Also, it would save overhead if you only perform the test for POST requests, since that is your concern.

Comment: The session isn't available during GetHttpHandler. Any ideas there?

Comment: Yes, but the FormCollection and the Cookie is.  Put the session id in a hidden field on the form or in an HttpCookie.

Comment: Taking your advice, I have built an `ActionFilterAttribute` instead. I've posted what I have so far up above - still working on it though.

Comment: an ActionFilter is perfectly acceptable, but it happens later on in the life cycle, so if you have any per request actions (such as logging) that are linked to the controller action, the process will still be logged.  The other advantages of an IRouteHandler is it stops the process at the earliest point before resources are allocated, it is virtually a singleton (at least on a per route basis), and it only has to be declared once for global functionality.

Comment: Alrighty, I've finished it, I think. I have updated my original post to include the full ActionFilterAttribute. Any `HttpPost` method can be decorated with this and it should prevent the user from being able to hammer the submit button.

Comment: I decided to stick with an ActionFilter because it's a little more granular.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases I'd say that this isn't worth fixing - if a user is going to do something as silly as clicking submit 20 times they should expect to get an error.

The only real fix for this is to set up your action to only accept the same form once - add a hidden field that is set to a random value when the form is loaded. When the form is posted, save that value somewhere temporarily and if it is already there you have a duplicate request that shouldn't do anything.

Comment: I'm not expecting a user to do it by accident, I'm expecting it to be done more maliciously. And to be clear, this isn't a case of "Click the button, get impatient, click again", this is a case of "c-c-c-c-c-c-c-c-c-c-c-c-c-c-c--cc--c-c-click!" right from the start.

Comment: What troubles me is that this isn't happening on other forms, but I'm not doing any of them different. The only thing different about this form is that it only has a single form field. But like, no one has seen this happen on the `Register` form. I don't know, this seems like a balatantly obvious problem with forms in general and it surprises me that after all these years I am just now encountering it. I have to assume _I_ I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the issue yourself, or is this just something you are seeing in the logs? If it is deliberate, JavaScript and standard validation won't help, because the values on each request are valid and JavaScript can be turned off.